# Elasticsearch migration filter

Tags: json, elasticsearch, filter, filtering, elasticsearch-5

This is my problem : I need to translate my filter / query syntax (elasticsearch 1.x) to elasticsearch 5.x syntax.

This is my query :

```
{
"query ": {
    "filtered ": {
        "query ": {
            "fuzzy_like_this ": {
                "like_text ": "    cin ",
                "max_query_terms ": 12,
                "fuzziness ": 0.7
            }
        },
        "filter ": {
            "and ": {
                "filters ": [{
                    "or ": {
                        "filters ": [{
                            "type ": {
                                "value ": "etude_patrimoine_architecture "
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I don't really understand elastic 5.x syntax with bool.

Any help to migrate this filter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the final solution :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "_all": {
                        "query": QUERYVALUE,
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "type": {
                            "value": VAL1
                        }
                    }, {
                        "type": {
                            "value": VAL2
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }],
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "geometry": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "envelope",
                            "coordinates": COORDARAY
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

- the `filtered/query` part goes in `bool/must`
- the `filtered/filter` part goes either in `bool/filter`, `bool/must_not` or `bool/should` depending on whether you need to AND, NOT, OR behavior.

Something like this should get you started:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         query
      ],
      "should": [
         queryLayers
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Val, i will try your solution. I had update my post to be more clear with json stringify.